# Mining stops after generating DAG for epoch

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethminer, miner

I first initiate the node using the genesis file with the command:

```
>geth init genesis.json
```

Then i start the blockchain network using the following command:

```
>geth --identity "node1" --rpc --rpcport "8001" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "node1" --port "30304" --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --autodag --networkid 123 --nat "any"
```

Then i open another command prompt and type

```
>geth attach
```

I could've used 'console' but i wanted to monitor network log properly.

Now i created an account and gave the command:

```
>miner.start()

I0310 11:14:39.402000 eth/backend.go:454] Automatic pregeneration of ethash    
DAG ON (ethash dir: C:\Users\Rahul13615\AppData\Ethash)
I0310 11:14:39.403000 eth/backend.go:461] checking DAG (ethash dir:    
C:\Users\Rahul13615\AppData\Ethash)
I0310 11:14:39.404000 node/node.go:296] IPC endpoint opened:   
\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
I0310 11:14:39.407000 node/node.go:366] HTTP endpoint opened: 
http://localhost:8001
I0310 11:15:31.755000 miner/miner.go:119] Starting mining operation (CPU=4 
TOT=5)
I0310 11:15:31.756000 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 1 with 0 
txs & 0 uncles. Took 1ms
I0310 11:15:31.757000 ethash.go:259] Generating DAG for epoch 0 (size 
1073739904)        
(0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
I0310 11:15:32.717000 ethash.go:276] Done generating DAG for epoch 0, it  
took 961ms
```

After this no new blocks are commited. It just stopped or is running slow. How should i remedy this situation and make it run fast?

Comment: Have you tried sending transactions in this network?
I think it stops when there are no new transactions to be mined..

Comment: Try adding `miner` to `rpcapi`.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have started the miner using geth console. Why I'm saying this, I couldn't see **--mine** in your geth initiation command.

This will be the same again even though miner is started.

This happens because of the Machine RAM capability, Just try the **eth.hashrate** and **eth.blockNumber**. If both return zero, your machine is struggling with computation power.

So I tried with AWS instance with some good RAM capabilities, blocks were created immediately without any delay.

Comment: hi seetharaman..i am facing the exact same issue and my server machine.. configuration is 64GB RAM 128GB and 16CPU..what might be possible workarounds?