# Mining hangs on Generating DAG in progress

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain, ipc

I am trying to initialize rpc using the below command and start miner using `miner.start(1);`

```
geth --rpcapi eth,web3,personal --rpc --networkid=15
```

Mining starts successfully with below logs but it doesn't proceed further and hangs here only.

```
INFO [08-28|18:20:52.808] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 percentage=98 elapsed=12.725s
INFO [08-28|18:20:53.063] Generating DAG in progress               epoch=1 percentage=99 elapsed=12.981s
INFO [08-28|18:20:53.065] Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=1 elapsed=12.983s
```

**Things i tried till now.**

1. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13610/41204

   action : 64GB RAM 128GB HD and 16CPU so this is not the problem i guess.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46430217/6572971

   action : Have set primary account using `eth.defaultAccount=eth.coinbase` which returns "0x-----"
3. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/39000/41204

   action : Have done as suggested but no luck.